# go hello world example results in unknown directive

Tags: go

I am using macos Monterey 12.0.1

I've installed go as described here:

https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started

I've initialized the module directory

```
~/projects/go
```

with

```
go mod init example/hello
```

I've created the hello world file with the content:

```
package main

import { 
  "fmt"
}

function main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello, world!")
}
```

Then I do

```
go run .
```

in the

```
~/projects/go
```

directory.

And I am getting:

```
[home]/projects/go/go.mod:1: unknown directive: package
[home]/projects/go/go.mod:3: unknown directive: import
[home]/projects/go/go.mod:5: unknown directive: function
[home]/projects/go/go.mod:6:3: unknown directive: fmt.Println
[home]/projects/go/go.mod:7: unknown directive: }
```

I know, I must have **committed** some unexcusable mistake somewhere but I can't figure out, where I've gone astray.

Comment: First use `func` instead of `function`. And the source code must go to a file with `.go` extension, not into `go.mod` file. Name it like `hello.go`.

Comment: @LongHike, be sure to work through https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/ if you haven't yet

Answer (score 3):

- You define functions with `func` in go, not `function`.
- And for imports you should use regular brackets, not curly ones.

The corrected version of your code is like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, world!")
}
```

See here: https://go.dev/play/p/AH8TPSfGkFd